# Window Open Javascript (Wrong Parameters)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, popup, window.open

So I'm trying to open a pop up window in IE8. So far no luck. It's telling me I have the wrong parameters in window.open() but when I look at all the parameters for window.open() it all looks right, suggestions?

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="one">Click Here</a>
<script language="javascript">
var vid1 = document.getElementById('video1');

if(vid1.addEventListener)
{
    vid1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        videoOne();
    },true);
}
else
{
    vid1.attachEvent('click', videoOne);
}

function videoOne(){
    window.open("http://www.yahoo.com","Case Study 1", 
                "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=650,height=400");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer doesn't support window names with spaces in them.

```
window.open("http://www.yahoo.com","CaseStudy1", 
            "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=650,height=400");
```

Answer (score 0):

Quentin is correct, although there is more information in the [MDN docs for `window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open):

> A string name for the new window. The name can be used as the target of links and forms using the target attribute of an  or  element. The name should not contain any blank space. Note that strWindowName does not specify the title of the new window.